# How to aggregate only few rows of data based on one column in SQL

Tags: sql

Here I am trying to display the single date column as two different dates - one as start date and the other as end date when we have there is only one transaction type. If we have two credit records - we need to sum up the amounts and the start date should be the 1st-row date and the 2nd-row date as the end date. If there is only one row of transaction type then the same date will be as the start date and end date.

Input :

```
Id, Date,Transaction_type, amount
1,'01/09/2021','credit',10
2,'02/09/2021','credit',20
3,'03/09/2021','debit',30
4,'04/09/2021','debit',40
5,'05/09/2021','credit',50
6,'06/09/2021','debit',60
7,'07/09/2021','credit',70
8,'08/09/2021','credit',80
9,'09/09/2021','debit',90
```

Output :

```
 Start_date, End_date, Transaction_type, amount
'01/09/2021','02/09/2021','credit',30
'03/09/2021','04/09/2021','debit',70
'05/09/2021','05/09/2021','credit',50
'06/09/2021','06/09/2021','debit',60
'07/09/2021','08/09/2021','credit',150
'09/09/2021','09/09/2021','debit',90
```

Comment: Gaps and islands.

Answer (score 0):

1st - Do not name columna as `Date`.
2nd - You should set another column to indicate which credit lines should be used as one.

At this form it's doable, but it's poorly designed. Do you read it with SQL or C#/Python/VBA etc? Any UI? What SQL are u using SQL server? Oracle? Can u use functions, procedures etc.

Escentially with procedure you could:

1. Create temp table
2. With while function insert data into that table
3. Read data from temp table
4. Destroy temp table.

Create Procedure:

```
Create Procedure dbo.TestExtract
As
BEGIN TRY
    declare @startID as int
    declare @endID as int

    declare @TT1 as varchar(20)
    declare @TT2 as varchar(20)

    --create temp table
    create table #temp(Start_date date, End_date Date, Transaction_type Varchar(50), amount Numeric(18))

    --get first id
    set @startID = (select top 1 ID from dbo.Test order by ID asc)
    set @endID = (select top 1 ID from dbo.Test order by ID desc)
    
    --loop from lowest to biggest id
    while @startID <= @endID
        begin 
            --get adjecent (with id) transaction types
            select top 1 @TT1 = Transaction_type from dbo.Test where ID = @startID
            select top 1 @TT2 = Transaction_type from dbo.Test where ID = @startID + 1
            --compare transaction adjecent types

            --if same get startd ID from first, and end date from second and sum both entries and iterate by 2
            if @TT1 = @TT2 
                begin
                    Insert Into #Temp
                    select  top 1
                            (select top 1 RecDate from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID) as Start_date, 
                            (select top 1 RecDate from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID + 1) as End_date,
                            (select top 1 Transaction_type from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID)as Transaction_type,
                            (select sum(amount) from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID or ID = @startID + 1) as amount
                    from dbo.Test
                    set @startID = @startID + 2
                end
            --if different get only record on one line and iterate by 1
            else
                begin
                    Insert Into #Temp
                    select  top 1
                            (select top 1 RecDate from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID) as Start_date, 
                            (select top 1 RecDate from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID) as End_date,
                            (select top 1 Transaction_type from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID) as Transaction_type,
                            (select amount from dbo.Test Where ID = @startID) as amount
                    from dbo.Test
                    set @startID = @startID + 1
                end
        end
        
        select * from #temp
        drop table #temp
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
Go
```

Extract with procedure:

```
exec dbo.TestExtract
```

Comment: Thank you so much...This works :).    Is there a way where we can work without a stored procedure and looping process (just to know)

Comment: You can use entire procedure as a query, but i do not recommend that.

Comment: okay, got it. Thanks much :)